# I am trying to set a hostname in windows powershell

Tags: powershell, system-administration

I am typing the command into the Windows Powershell:

> hostnamectl set-hostname great.wave.com

I don't understand the possible reason as to why it is not working.

[image: windows powershell screenshot]

Comment: `hostnamectl` is a systemd utility - and there's no systemd on Windows. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: It's fairly self-explanatory - it can't find systemd/hostnamectl. Look online - there's plenty of articles telling you which utilities have native commands and how to run Linux programs from Powershell.

Comment: You're running Windows.  Windows is a different OS than unix.  Commands like `hostnamectl` don't work on Windows, because they're Unix commands, which work on Unix, which is a different operating system.  If you search for 'rename windows computer' you'll get closer.  However you can't rename a computer and set the domain with the same command, which is what you're trying to do.

Comment: you can also use the infamous `--%` to tell posh to not translate it

Comment: Thank you, I realised my mistake and I googled the windows command then I successfully changed the hostname

Comment: @AAA Great! Post your solution in an answer below! :-)

Comment: This is the command I used to rename the hostname: Rename-Computer –NewName winserv -Restart